# Question in Lebesgue integrable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $g$ be a measurable function satisfying: $∀$ $σ∈[c,d]$ , there exists $δ>0$ such that $∫_E|g| <∞$ where $E=[σ-δ, σ+δ]$. Prove that $g$  is Lebesgue integrable on $[c, d]$.

Comment: One thing special about $[c,d]$ is that it is compact.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Cover $[c, d]$ with sets of the form $(\sigma - \delta, \sigma + \delta)$ for all $\sigma \in [c, d]$ and use the compactness of $[c, d]$.

Comment: I didn't get anything from the Hint :(

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=σ_1 <σ_2 < ....<σ_n =b$ and $E_k = (σ_k-δ,σ_k+δ)$. Then $⋃_1^n$ $E_k$$=(a-δ,b+δ)$.

clearly that $[a,b] ⊂$ $⋃_1^n$ $E_k$. Now, since $f$ integrable over $E_k$.
Then by monotonicity the proof complete.

Is that enough?